# Laggy performance 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, firefox, intel, performance

I have a mini pc, a so-called Beelink X55, with windows on it. I decided to try Ubuntu, and made a dual boot system, and all was fine. I love the look, the customizations, etc, but this thing holds me back. The overall performance is quite poor. I know this pc has it's limitation, and it's not a power device, but it can handle windows without any issue, for basic things, browsing, some light editing stuff like gimp, inkscape, etc. I can't imagine, that windows needs less power, than linux. Am I wrong?
The animations are laggy, like if it was 20fps. (monitor is 60). Apps are launching okay though, but still, I can definitely feel the difference when I go back to windows. Not talking about Firefox... That's just a nightmare. Very laggy scrolling, often freezing for some secs. I have read a lot of feedback about this, I tried many tweaks, but nothing has changed. I don't wanna always compare, but on w10 is smooth as it should be.
So my question is, is there anything, I can do for it? Is there something, that I did wrong, or poor support for this pc, what could be the thing? I accidentally deleted the full partition of ubuntu, but I'm planning to reinstall soon, so I'm ready to give any answers when I'm done, if it's needed to find the solution. Btw the pc has an Intel UHD graphics 605 (J5005) with 8 gigs of ddr4 ram.

Comment: You seem to be describing common out-of-memory symptoms. Check the output of `free -h` now to confirm that all your RAM is being recognized by the system.

Comment: It is a known problem with Beelink X55: https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/10/05/beelink-x55-review/. Apparently, still unresolved.